# \iint already defined

Tags: errors, packages

I know this has already been asked a lot, but the previous answers don't seem to help. As the title says, I have an error telling me the commands \iint, \iiint, \iiiint, \idotsint and \openbox are alredy defined. I read that the issue should be solved adding [nointegrals] to the package wasysym and loading amsmath before it, but even if I do that the error remains. By the way, I never redefine \iint or any of the commands above. The order of the loaded packages is as follows:

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{tikz,pgf}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1.25in, left=1.25in, right=1.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{abstract}
\usepackage[nointegrals]{wasysym}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

Comment: If I add enough code to make your code fragment into a document, it compiles without error. Please update your code to include a small test document with a class.

Comment: Please also add the first few lines of your log file.

Comment: It uses the aip-cp class, other than that I don't do anything before startinjg to write

Comment: I don't know if it may be the cause

Comment: Problem solved by using \let \relax. I still don't understand why it occured though

Comment: Your class loads the `txfonts` package. You'd already get an error from `\documentclass{aip-cp}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
content...
\end{document}` without the `wasysym` package

Comment: The proposed dupe + `\let\openbox\relax` should avoid the error